# Modify react-boilerplate to nest injected reducers under a single key of the store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-boilerplate

`react-boilerplate` has a utility `injectReducer` that is used to allow a reducer to be asynchronously attached to the `store`, and in the `reducers.js` file for the entire application, `createReducer` spreads out these `injectedReducers` into the state so that you have a state shape as follows:

```
{
  route: routeReducer,
  language: languageProviderReducer,
  container1: container1Reducer,
  container2: container2Reducer,
  container3: container3Reducer,
}
```

I would like instead to spread out these container-specific reducers to a subkey of the global state like so:

```
{
  route: routeReducer,
  language: languageProviderReducer,
  ui: {
    container1: container1Reducer,
    container2: container2Reducer,
    container3: container3Reducer,
  }
}
```

I naively tried to modify the `reducers.js` method `createReducer` like so:

```
export default function createReducer(injectedReducers) {
  return combineReducers({
    route: routeReducer,
    language: languageProviderReducer,
    ui: (injectedReducers) ? combineReducers(injectedReducers) : ((state = {}) => state),
  });
}
```

or maybe:

```
export default function createReducer(injectedReducers) {
  return combineReducers({
    route: routeReducer,
    language: languageProviderReducer,
    ui: combineReducers(injectedReducers || {}),
  });
}
```

But now when I try to load any container, I get an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null`.

What is the easiest path to achieve the kind of state shape I want using injected reducers and `react-boilerplate`?

Comment: did you try to `state = null` in your injected reducer and then `return state` at the end of the function in the reducer ?

Comment: No, my injected reducer works fine when injected the normal way that `react-boilerplate` does, by spreading in combineReducers

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos Did you ever find a resolution for this? What did you end up doing?

Comment: @nikjohn yes, I did... I'll write up an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key for me I believe was to only add the `ui` key when it was needed (when at least one `injectedReducers` was present).

```
/**
 * Creates the main reducer with the dynamically injected ones
 */
export default function createReducer(injectedReducers) {
  const reducersToCombine = {
    form: formReducer,
    language: languageProviderReducer,
    route: routeReducer,
  };

  if (injectedReducers && Object.keys(injectedReducers).length > 0) {
    reducersToCombine.ui = combineReducers(injectedReducers);
  }

  return combineReducers(reducersToCombine);
}
```

Comment: Did it and realized that if I attach same reducer to several keys like { `forms` : {`id1` : reducer, `id2`: reducer}} I also need <id> in action since now I have two reducers that handle same action. Though they mutate separate part of state, without id in action both may mutate on one action specific to concrete id.